# How can I schedule a reboot mid-way through a wix burn chain?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Currently I have a chain that checks for and installs the following pre-requisites if they are missing:

1. Windows Installer 4.5
2. .net Framework 4
3. Sql Server Express 2008 R2

Unfortunately installer needs to reboot the machine after installing #1 otherwise the Sql server install fails. If the user is prompted to restart the machine, this is suppressed and the installer just continues with #2. How can I reboot the machine (if #1 was installed) and then automatically continue with the install?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to chain the pre-reqs? Is it WiX Burn?

Comment: Yep was in the title! ;) FYI it's Wix 3.6 RC0.

Comment: After installing no 1, why don't you run a bat file to reboot? I have never done this just a suggestion.

Comment: I have considered a bat file to reboot, however when #1 tries to reboot , the bootstrapper crashes so I assume that a bat file will do the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I think I've found out how to do this. Basically I needed to specify the forceReboot option on the child ExitCode of the WixInstaller ExePackage.

```
<ExePackage Id="WinXp_x86"
              Cache="no"
              Compressed="no"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Permanent="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              InstallCommand="/norestart /passive"
              SourceFile="WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe"
              DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/6/1/261fca42-22c0-4f91-9451-0e0f2e08356d/WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe"
              DetectCondition="WINXP_X86_NEEDS_INSTALLER" >
    <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot" />
</ExePackage>
```

This correctly tells the user to reboot the machine, and when it restarts the bootstrap installer window re-opens, but the user has to click on the "Install" button again. This it seems is a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29054899) in the RC0 (3.6.2803.0) but has been fixed in the latest sources (3.6.2830.0). I've just built the latest sources and trying to verify...